# How can I take the highest ranking filter condition that ends up matching in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Wording of my question might be confusing so let me explain.  Say I have an array of strings.  They are ranked in order of the best case scenario match.  So at index 0 we want this to always exist in the dataframe column, but if it doesn't then index 1 is the next best option.  I have written this logic like this, but I don't feel like this is the most efficient way to have done this.  Is there another way of doing it that is better?

The datasets are quite small, but I fear this can't really scale very well.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

val nameArray = Array[String]("Name", "Name%", "%Name%", "Person Name", "Person Name%", "%Person Name%")

nameArray.foreach(x => {
  val nameDf = df.where("text like '" + x + "'")

  if(nameDf.count() > 0){
    nameDf.show(1)
    break()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are order according to preference from left (highest precedence) to right (lowest precedence) and lower precedence patterns already cover higher precedence ones (it doesn't look like it is the case in your example) you generate expression like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def matched(df: DataFrame, nameArray: Seq[String], c: String = "text") = {

  val matchIdx = nameArray.zipWithIndex.foldRight(lit(-1)){
    case ((s, i), acc) => when(col(c) like s, lit(i)).otherwise(acc)
  }

  df.select(max(matchIdx)).first match {
    case Row(-1)     => None  // No pattern matches all records
    case Row(i: Int) => Some(nameArray(i))
  }
}
```

Usage examples:

```
matched(Seq("Some Name", "Name", "Name Surname").toDF("text"), Seq("Name", "Name%", "%Name%"))
// Option[String] = Some(%Name%)
```

There are two advantages of this method:

- Only one action is required.
- Pattern matching can be short circuited.

If pre-conditions are not satisfied you can

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val unmatchedCount: Map[String, Long] = df.select(
  nameArray.map(s => count(when(not($"text" like s), 1)).alias(s)): _*
).first.getValuesMap[Long](nameArray)
```

Unlike the first approach it will check all patterns, but it requires only one action.

Comment: Awesome thank you, what if I could put them in order.  Does it make it any more efficient?

Comment: I posted an edit, I hope it explains possible advantages of each approach.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Don't mention it (of course upvote would appreciated :) [if you're satisfied with the answer] )

Comment: In your usage example, it returns %Name%, but is it possible to have it return Name instead since it was the furthest one to the left?  For example, I would want it to find the word "Name", but if it can't find "Name", then "Names" would be second best option and it would match Name%.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the goal. `name` won't match all records, only `"Name"`. If you want to find the first pattern that matches any of the records, then replacing `max(matchIdx)` with `min(matchIdx)` should do the trick.

Comment: You can further experiment with different orderings of pattern and `min` / `max`, and if none satisfy the requirements, then the second option, should give you much more comprehensive overview.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bring this back from the dead.  This function is helping me greatly, but what if I wanted to return the actual text that we submitted to match on instead of returning the matched value from the array. Is there an easy way to rewrite this to perform that?

Comment: Maybe something like this (not tested): `nameArray.foldRight(lit(null)){
    case (s, acc) => when(col(c) like s, lit(s)).otherwise(acc)
  }`?

Comment: I think it's close, but it's returning the string that matched from the array. I was hoping to get the actual string that matched the criteria, because we have some instances where we are using wild cards to match on.  I want it to give me all the strings that passed the matching test essentially.

Comment: Like, instead of returning s, I want the value of col(c).